# How to Override core customer model In Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer, overrides

I have to override customer ResourceModel's `customer.php` file in my custom module.
I have tried but its not working.so what is correct way to override Model?   I follow below steps to override Model.

I have my own module called `Namespace_Module` with a `di.xml` file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer"   type="Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Customer" />
</config>
```

Then I have created php file,   `Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Customer.php` and try to override core file.but its not working for me.

So please anyone help me to solve my problem.

Comment: You must not do this. What do you want achieved?

Comment: I see the question was asked long back, but the issues are still relevant. In my case, I want to remove the Required validation of "Email" and there is no way to do that other than overriding the Resource model at vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/Customer.php. The thing is that in _beforeSave() they explicitly check for whether the customer have Email and fails validation if not. My question is what is the point of 'is_required' property for the email in eav_attribute model? Anyone can create a disposable email nowadays and think about the spam registration you may get!

Answer (score 12):

your file **Namespace\Modulename\etc\di.xml** code as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer" type="Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Customer" />
</config>
```

Your Model code file **Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Customer.php**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel;

class Customer extends \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer
{


    protected function _beforeSave(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $customer)
    {
        exit('test');
        //your code here
    }
}
?>
```

hope it will helpful to you

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
I have tried this code and this code is working,it will call custom module's _beforeSave action but I want to comment  $this->_validate($customer); line for my custom module.but it will not working.It give error

Comment: post your error

Comment: "First Name" is a required value.
"First Name" length must be equal or greater than 1 characters.
"Last Name" is a required value.
"Last Name" length must be equal or greater than 1 characters.
"My Attribute" is a required value.
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\module-customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer.php(143): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer->_validate(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Customer))C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Explorer\Logindialog\Model\ResourceModel\Customer.php:Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer
I got this error.

Comment: add your code and error screen shot to your question

Comment: I am doing same things to override shipping Model file but it's not working and only display Loader.